# Multiple jQuery posts not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Problem**:
In an ASP.NET MVC project using jQuery, the [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function only rarely returns data, when I expect it to always return data.

**Question**:
Why does my `.post()` function rarely activate the success callback function - even though each post returns a status code of 200 OK?

**Details**:
I have 10 empty spans defined in an ASP.NET cshtml view. Each span is followed in html by a script, that calls a javascript function called `ShowConstraints()`:

```
<div>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string tempID = "span" + i;
        <span id="@tempID"></span>
        <script>ShowConstraints("@tempID")</script><br />
    }
</div>
```

The resulting html looks like this for each `span`, before the script is called:

```
<div>
    <span id="span0"></span>
    <script>ShowConstraints("span0")</script><br>
    ...
```

The `ShowConstraints()` function is as follows:

```
function ShowConstraints(outputId) {
    outputEl = "#" + outputId;
    $(outputEl).html("Calculating info...");
    $.post("/TestURL/TestPost", function (data) {
            $(outputEl).html(data);
    });
}
```

The returned value from `/TestURL/TestPost` is always `<span>Returned!</span>`.

I know the posting function has been successfully called when a span shows "Calculating info...". And I know a successfull post has happened when the span changes to show "Returned!".

However, when running only one or two of the spans show "Returned!". The rest show "Calculating info..."

As additional info, when I debug the javascript and step through, everything works as expected, and all spans show "Returned!".

Much thanks.

Comment: The fact that it works when you debug makes it sound like an asynchronous issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really wouldn't recommend executing code like this from within your HTML.  It's bound to lead to inconsistencies, especially with multiple calls being made using multiple `<script>` tags.

You should be executing it on the page load from within the main bulk of your JavaScript code, something like:

```
// On the page load
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Get the spans that we want to loop through
  $('span.mySpans').each(function(index, value) {

      var outputId = $(this).attr('id');

      ShowConstraints(outputId);

  });
});
```

With the HTML something like:

```
<span class="mySpans" id="span0"></span>
<span class="mySpans" id="span1"></span>
<span class="mySpans" id="span2"></span>
<span class="mySpans" id="span3"></span>
```

Comment: Results in nothing displaying... even when correcting quotation formatting.

Comment: hmmm sad times.  Try updating that variable so it is new within the scope of each function call.

Comment: thank you for multiple edits to your answer to try and track this down. Unfortunately even when changing to execute under `$(document).ready` with `.each` to loop through, I'm still getting same problem.

Comment: Um, actually seems to work when I loop through by element type using `.each()`, rather than looping through by class. I'll work some more on it. Eager to see your jquery solution alluded to in your last comment.

Comment: Seems to be working now. I'll mark as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is you're calling a bunch of these all at once and by the time some of the information has returned

```
outputEl = "#" + outputId;
```

Is now set to something other than the original outputEl.
You could try and delay the functions so they don't all call at the same time, or try and chain them in as callback functions.